# Using qualifications in amazon mechanical turk clt

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am using aws command line tools to post HITs on amazon mechanical turk. I'm trying to use qualifications to prevent workers from doing the same HIT more than once. I've created the qualification and assigned it to workers who've done the HIT. Then, in my exp.properties file I have the following:

```
   qualification.2.QualificationTypeId:[ID of qualification]
   qualification.2.Comparator:NotEqualTo
   qualification.2.IntegerValue:1
   qualification.private.2:false
```

The HIT posts no problem, but this doesn't seem to prevent workers to whom I've assigned '1' for this qualification from completing the HIT. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's easier to use a DoesNotExist comparator value (assuming the CLT allows it).

Comment: Thanks, for the moment I am using an older version that doesn't support that comparator. Is there a problem with using NotEqualTo though?

Comment: If you use a `NotEqualTo`, then the HIT is only available to workers who have been assigned a score on the qualification. If the QualificationType is requestable, then that's not a big deal, but it requires you to configure an automatic score or manually handle the requests. And you have to be cautious about allowing "re-requests" that allow workers with a score to automatically obtain a different one, which might explain why you're seeing workers with score 1 completing the HIT. By contrast, `DoesNotExist` makes a HIT available to any worker who has not even been assigned a score.

Comment: Ok, but I certainly have plenty of people completing the HIT who are *not* assigned a score for that qualification. So if that's how it's supposed to work, then I must be doing something wrong! FYI, all the workers who are "repeats" still have a score of 1.

Comment: Have you looked at the HIT in the worker web interface to ensure it looks correct? This sound like strange behavior.